# Converting KG to Pounds program

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass {


int i = 1;

public static void main(String[] args)
{


    String output = "";                       
    System.out.println("kilograms | pounds");
    System.out.println("--------+-----------");
    for ( i = 1; i <= 199; i ++)
    {            
       // Every table line in between
    System.out.printLn(“| “+i+” | “+i*2.2+” |”);
        }
    System.out.println(output);
    } //end method
} // end class
```

what's wrong here, why can't I run it??trying to display a list of KG to pound from 1 to 199

Comment: Use normal double quotes: `System.out.println("| "+i+" | "+i*2.2+" |");`

Comment: That `i` variable needs to either be declared static, or moved into the `main` method. I'd suggest the latter.

Comment: @crush It would work with space. No problem there.

Comment: I see at least 3 compiler-checked errors. What IDE are you using? Or are you simply compiling from command line? In any case, it really helps getting accustomed with the compiler's error messages

Comment: Also, when you're trying to get help for a problem, you should actually state what the problem is.  As it turns out, there are about 3 or 4 and counting based on the answers here but it helps us to help you if we know what problem(s) you're trying to resolve.

Comment: `printLn` should be `println` btw.

Comment: @RohitJain Yeah, you're right. Blonde moment.

Comment: Yep, you're at least getting an error message about referencing a member field in a static context, due to the way you've declared `i`.  And it appears that you used a word processor rather than general-purpose text editor to create the text, causing the wrong double quote (`"`) characters to be used.

Comment: You can't run it, because you can't compile it. That was easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some typos. This should compile:

```
//Removed import because you aren't using it

public class NewClass {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {                 
    System.out.println("kilograms | pounds");
    System.out.println("--------+-----------");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 199; i ++) 
    // define i at this point because it's only used in this scope
    {            
      System.out.println("| " + i + " | " + (2.2 * i) + " |");
      // Use normal "
      // you misspelled println
      // put parenthesis around calculations
    }
    System.out.println("");
  } //end method
} // end class
```

You should consider using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). It highlights errors like the ones above.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do math in the middle of concatenating strings.  Wrap i*2.2 in parentheses and you should be fine.  Right now, you're appending the value of i to the String and then trying to multiply that String by 2.2.

Comment: No, the multiplication has a higher precedence than the concatenation.

Comment: A lot of times, we are so used to doing things that are considered "good practice" that we forget that they aren't actually required.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for-loop so you're not using the class member `i` (which you should delete):

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= 199; i ++) //could be i < 200 though, if I was being picky...
```

Change this line so you have **println** and not **printLn**, and use normal double quotes:

```
System.out.println("| " + i + " | " + i * 2.2 + " |");
```